# can't use resolve data in modal

Tags: angularjs, scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Have problem sending data to modal with `resolve`.
I have this template:

```
<div class="split wrapper" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtr">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tablesModal">
    <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{ test }}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body tables-list">
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
</div>
```

controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('appCtr', ['$scope', '$modal', function($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.openCT = function(size){
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'tablesModal',
            controller : 'appCtr',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                test: function(){
                    return 'example';
                }
            }
        });
    }
}]);
```

but i nothing shows in modal title..
What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resolve()` function is called when dialog is closed and modal data is passed `then()` handler.

To fix issue add `test` in scope:

```
$scope.test = "Modal Title";
```

Comment: Thanks.. just one more question, when i add `controller : 'appCtr'` it will take scope from that controller, but it will regenerate variables? that is happening to me now, when i console log variable from controller it shows me correct data, but when i use it in modal, that data is reseted, init value..